# Add number of minutes to DateTime for a specific duration

Tags: excel, vba, datetime

I have in cell A1 a starting DateTime as 01-01-2021 00:00:00.

In another cell C2 I have a duration specifed as 240 minutes and in C3 I have a specified interval in minutes it could be 1 minute intervals or perhaps 5. I would like to fill out DateTime based on the duration and intervals from A2 and down.

```
1 minute interval 240 duration
01-01-2021 00:00:00
01-01-2021 00:01:00
...
01-01-2021 04:00:00
```

Different interval same duration:

```
5 minute intervals
01-01-2021 00:00:00
01-01-2021 00:05:00
...
01-01-2021 04:00:00
```

I've solved this by using a formula `=IF(Y<$A$2+TIME(0;$C$2;0)-TIME(0;$C$3;0);A2+TIME(0;$C$3;0);"")` but would like to convert this to VBA.

[image]

[image]

```
Sub Time()

    Selection.NumberFormat = "dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm"

    Dim StartTime As Date
    Dim newDate As Date
    Dim CountOfMinutes As Double
    Dim i As Double
    
    i = Sheets("Ark1").Range("C3")
    
    CountOfMinutes = Sheets("SVK stationer").Range("C2")
    
    Set StartTime = Sheets("SVK stationer").Date("A2")
        
    newDate = DateAdd("n", CountOfMinutes, StartTime)
    
    For Each cell In StartTime
        If IsEmpty(cell) = False Then
            cell.Value = cell.Value + DateAdd("n", i + CountOfMinutes, StartTime)
        End If
        
End Sub
```

Comment: instead of `TIME` in VBA have a look at the `TimeSerial` method.

Comment: Not so clear (for me) what you have in order to accomplish  what you explain... Are the DateTime records in A:A and C:C, and each row should be processed? And is duration a constant to be set for the calculation, or to also be taken from the sheet? What does "Y" represent in your formula?

Comment: @FaneDuru DateTime is in A:A, and the duration + intervals are specified in the sheet in a different cell C2 and C3. I've added images

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general method is:

```vb
NextTime = DateAdd("n", i * CountOfMinutes, StartTime)
```

So, loop through the rows while increasing `i` by one to calculate `NextTime`.

Comment: I've added a bit of code to show what I was trying. But I can see you use the DateAdd rather than TimeSerial. Also my code isn't really working/done.

Comment: As you can see, `DateAdd` is simpler and the direct method to use as `TimeSerial` only can return the time part.